# How to select addtion of two columns of a table through hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Suppose i have a table Student

```
 - ID         Name         Sub1      Sub2
 - 1          Deepika       99        89
 - 2          Shubham       78        90
```

I want my hibernate application to provide me the following result

```
 - ID         Name        Sub1      Sub2      Total
 - 1          Deepika       90       80        170
 - 2          Shubham       78       90        168
```

i.e my sql query is

```
select id name, sub1, sub2, sub1+sub2 as total
from employee
```

How can i do this in Hibernate? What changes should i make in my hbm.xml file and bean class?

Comment: Can't you just add a getter method to the entity bean class that return the sum of those both columns?

Comment: How are you mapping your objects?

Answer (score 0):

Using addScalar() you can fetch any additional row than the existing information without changing the xml. For more details refer [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html)

Otherwise you need to change the xml and bean class corresponding to the new table structure.

Comment: Actually the database i am working on have too many columns. I dont want to call addscalar for each of them. So is there a way around. And i also want the new column containing the sum to set in my bean corresponding the table.

Comment: while entering the data in the database I mean the marks you can enter the sum too... that way you can retrieve it directly.

Comment: i cant to do that.....one way i have found           <property   name="fullname" formula="concat(firstname, ' ', lastname)"/>
what should be the formula to add marks1 and makrks 2 fields.

Comment: For forumla attribute the documentation reads the following :-
formula (optional): an arbitrary SQL expression that is executed when a type has to be evaluated. It allows content-based discrimination.
You can follow it up from [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html)

Comment: Then I guess (column1+column2) would suffice.